# pontryagin dual and maps between spectra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given two spectra $A$ and $B$, the set $[A,B]$ of homotopy classes of maps from $A$ to $B$ forms an abelian group. Can the dual abelian group $\text{Hom}([A,B],\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ be expressed as a group of homotopy classes of maps between spectra?

The *Brown-Comenetz dual* $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}E$ of a spectrum $E$ is defined [here](http://math.mit.edu/~vstojanoska/talk3.pdf). A key property of $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}E$ is that its homotopy is dual of that of $E$ in the sense that $\pi_*I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}E=\text{Hom}(\pi_*E,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.

Naively, I suspect that $\text{Hom}([A,B],\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ can be expressed in terms of $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}A$ and $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}B$.

What if I replace ${\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}$ by ${\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}$ or ${\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstandings.  The homotopy groups of $I_\mathbb{Z}E$ are not the Pontryagin duals of those of $E$ but the derived $\mathbb{Z}$-duals, up to a spectral sequence (see slide 7 in your link).  When $E$ has torsion homotopy groups, the Brown-Comenetz dual $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}E$ will have Pontryagin dual homotopy groups.  In most cases, $[A,B]$ will not have any natural topology, so I don't know what you mean when you ask for it to be locally compact.

Comment: You can also define a functor $I_{\mathbb{T}}$ that represents Pontryagin duality on all spectra (by Brown representability, just like for $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}$ and $I_\mathbb{Q}$).  However, a priori these Pontryagin dual groups will just be abstract abelian groups without a natural topology, so this gives you nothing useful that you didn't already have from $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}$ and $I_\mathbb{Q}$.  Maybe you can enrich this functor to land in some more structured category such that you can recover the topology on the homotopy groups.

Comment: The category of spectra is closed symmetric monoidal, so one can ask for a hom spectrum rather than merely a hom set and then ask for a description of the Spanier-Whitehead, Anderson, or Brown-Comenetz duals of this spectrum, I guess.

Comment: @EricWofsey. You are correct that I had some misunderstandings. Firstly, I mixed up my duals: I am interested in the BC dual. Secondly, forget what I said about local compactness.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, so I guess a related question is whether $I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}\text{hom}(A,B)$ can be expressed in terms of the BC duals of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The answer to your question is obviously *yes, since any abelian group arises as the group of homotopy classes of maps between certain spectra*. If you want BC-duals to show up, your abelian group is $\pi_0I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}F(A,B)$, where $F(A,B)$ is the function spectrum. If you want to use the BC-duals of $A$ and $B$, you should first try to anser your question for ordinaryt abelian groups instead of spectra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the closest thing there is to what you are looking for.  Let $G$ be any injective (i.e., divisible) abelian group.  Then there is a spectrum $I_G$ representing the cohomology theory $X\mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(\pi^s_*(X),G)$.  For any $A$ and $B$, we can then describe the dual $\operatorname{Hom}([A,B],G)$ as $[F(A,B),I_G]$.

In the special case that either $A$ or $B$ is a finite spectrum, however, we can do better than this.  If $DA=F(A,S)$ is the Spanier-Whitehead dual of $A$, we have $$[F(A,B),I_G]=[DA\wedge B,I_G]=[DA,F(B,I_G)].$$

Since $F(B,I_G)$ is just what we call $I_GB$, we can thus describe the dual of $[A,B]$ as $[DA,I_GB]$.